# Stack Overflow Careers tag search

Tags: bug, jobs, tag-search

I want to search Stack Overflow Careers, only for jobs that have at least one of the following tags `r` or `machine-learning`. I tried the following

1. Type the URL `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/R+or+machine-learning`
2. I tried to type `[r] [machine-learning]` in the search text box.

[image]

The problem is that it still gives me a lot of jobs that are not tagged as `r` or `machine-learning` specially when I click on the `most recent` tab:

What is the best way to search only for jobs that are tagged as `machine-learning` or `r`?

Comment: Have you tried the `relevance` tab?

Comment: At first I thought it might be listing all jobs with any tag *containing* `r` - but it's even worse than that, [searching for tag `d`](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/d) returns a job on which the *only* tag is `java`! So who knows what it's doing...

Comment: The problem seems to affect only the most recent tab ([using the or keyboard work for the relevance tab](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=R+or+machine-learning)). We're going to look into it.

Comment: @NaderHisham the relevance tab shows results sorted by match with the search terms (using elasticsearch as a search engine)

Comment: @AurélienGasser yeah I got the point , but is there any way to exclude jobs that don't have these tags even for the relevance tab, another thing also when I add this to my RSS fedd it's retrieving all jobs without any kind of filtering

Comment: We intentionally don't search only tags, but also post bodies. Careers doesn't have user-driven tagging (only the post's owner and moderators can change tags) so we want to include untagged or mis-tagged jobs as well. The most recent tab shows even very distant matches, but in this case it's letting too many through. I'll see if I can tweak the algorithm to give better results here.