# It should be possible to search by more than one tag on Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, jobs, search

Currently it is only possible to search by one tag.

So, for instance, I can search by the "Haskell" tag. I can also search by the "pair-programming" tag. I cannot however search for all listings that have both these tags.

This is possible on StackOverflow for questions, but not on Careers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, the job search doesn't exclusively take tags into consideration: job listing bodies [are also searched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258646/stack-overflow-careers-tag-search#comment842849_258646). For this reason, you might see jobs that don't have the [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) tag in the search results when you search for "Haskell".

We would like to make it possible to search *strictly* by tag, and also (to answer your question) to provide some way to perform boolean OR/AND searches. We haven't been able to do it just yet but it's definitely part of the features we would like to build.